# form-control transfers wrong infomation

Tags: html

I have this snippet of code, so visitors to my page must input their phone number so I can contact them.

It works fine; it validates the information but whenever someone puts "+45" or something in front of their phone number (like this +4512345678), I get this "2147483647".

```
<div class="form">
    <input type="phone"
           class="form-control"
           placeholder="Phone"
           name="fieldNumb"
    <input pattern=".{7,15}" required title="input number">
</div>
```

What's the logic behind that? And how do I solve it?

Comment: That's the maximum value of a signed integer.  You should handle phone numbers as strings, not numbers.

Comment: Alright. I handle is at strings and now it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

use `<select>` for country codes. it'll easy to handle for you and your user and validate it using javascript before sending. so user can use only (0-9). also use type='text' because there is a max value  for int